# SETUID not working in my laptop

Tags: bash, permissions, 20.04, root, cat

Suppose i have two files

```
total 8
-r-sr-xr-x 1 root root 34 Oct  8 17:36 openroot.sh
-rwx------ 1 root root 38 Oct  8 17:34 root.txt
```

Content in *root.txt* :

```
Hi I am root file.
```

Content in *openroot.sh* :

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami
cat root.txt
```

And now i am regular user *(for example : person1)*. I execute command below:

```
./openroot.sh
```

The output is below :

```
person1
cat: root.txt: Permission denied
```

which means i cannot open root.txt.
How does it happen?

Comment: You don't have permission to it, your 'regular' user isn't root, and root owns that file (and there are NO permissions for other users as per your first paste)

Comment: setuid only works for binary executables, it is ignored for all interpreted executables. like shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons Linux ignores the SUID bit for shell scripts. See for example http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html for some reasons.

So your shell script doesn't run as root and isn't allowed to open the text file.

Comment: Thanks all... :)